# Next.js Page using Antd Components Doesn't Load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I am setting up nextjs with antd using less based on the official example at next/examples github page. My nextjs page using antd component doesn't load when click on the link to the page. Those other pages without antd component loads up successfully.

Below are the codes which I used to setup with-ant-design-less. I doubt there is any syntax error in the codes cause I just copied from next's official examples site

my full code [link](https://github.com/myhendry/lab-mongo/tree/master/next) in case you like to take a look

Anyone encountered such behavior and has managed to resolve it? Thanks

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const lessToJS = require("less-vars-to-js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/antd-custom.less"), "utf8")
);

// fix: prevents error when .less files are required by node
if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
  require.extensions[".less"] = file => {};
}

module.exports = withLess({
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: themeVariables // make your antd custom effective
  }
});
```

**antd-custom.less**

```
@primary-color: #52c41a;

@layout-header-height: 40px;
@border-radius-base: 2px;
```

**signin.jsx**

```
import {
  Form,
  Select,
  InputNumber,
  DatePicker,
  Switch,
  Slider,
  Button
} from "antd";

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;

export default () => (
  <div style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
    <Form layout="horizontal">
      <FormItem
        label="Input Number"
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}
      >
        <InputNumber
          size="large"
          min={1}
          max={10}
          style={{ width: 100 }}
          defaultValue={3}
          name="inputNumber"
        />
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </FormItem>

      <FormItem label="Switch" labelCol={{ span: 8 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}>
        <Switch defaultChecked name="switch" />
      </FormItem>

      <FormItem label="Slider" labelCol={{ span: 8 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}>
        <Slider defaultValue={70} />
      </FormItem>

      <FormItem label="Select" labelCol={{ span: 8 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}>
        <Select
          size="large"
          defaultValue="lucy"
          style={{ width: 192 }}
          name="select"
        >
          <Option value="jack">jack</Option>
          <Option value="lucy">lucy</Option>
          <Option value="disabled" disabled>
            disabled
          </Option>
          <Option value="yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
        </Select>
      </FormItem>

      <FormItem
        label="DatePicker"
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 8 }}
      >
        <DatePicker name="startDate" />
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem style={{ marginTop: 48 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 8, offset: 8 }}>
        <Button size="large" type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          OK
        </Button>
        <Button size="large" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </FormItem>
    </Form>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: the link doesn't work because you are using a private repo change it to public

Comment: sorry. i have changed the repo to public. thanks :)

Comment: Hi. Please note the next folder in my current repo is working. I cloned someone else's example which uses antd and is working ok. my previous codes next-x190519 which followed nextjs github examples still can't work

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve your issue? I have the similar problem and the only notable difference in the page that isn't loading is that it's using a component that imports CSS

Comment: I've found this issue is open on their [Github Page](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282). The current workaround is importing an empty style sheet into your _app.js

Comment: Thanks MNSH. I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I ll take a look at the open issue. Thanks for pointing out the open issue

Comment: This issue solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542802/build-error-occurred-in-node-modules-antd-lib-style-index-css7/57543812#57543812

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for next.js & antd to work together is to create `_app.js` on `pages` folder with the following code:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

no need for additional adjustments.