# How to configure nextjs 9 and ant design less compatibility?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, react-dom

After upgrading `react`,`react-dom` and `nextjs` this error happens :

> Build error occurred
>   /home/lenovo/.../node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.css:7
>   body {
>   ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:22)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32) {
>   type: 'SyntaxError',
>   '$error': '$error'
>   }
>   events.js:180
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
>   Error: write EPIPE
>   ...
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>   at internal/child_process.js:810:39
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
>   errno: 'EPIPE',
>   code: 'EPIPE',
>   syscall: 'write'
>   }
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

This is my **next.config.js**:

```
const nextConfig = {
    distDir: '_next',

    onDemandEntries: {
        maxInactiveAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
        pagesBufferLength: 5,
    },

    webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
        !dev &&
        config.plugins.push(
            new BrotliPlugin({
                asset: '[path].br[query]',
                test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
                threshold: 10240,
                minRatio: 0.7,
            }),
        );

        !dev &&
        config.plugins.push(
            new CompressionPlugin({
                filename: '[path].gz[query]',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
                threshold: 10240,
                minRatio: 0.7,
            }),
        );
        return config;
    },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [withImages],
        [withCss],
        [
            withSass,
            {
                cssModules: true,
                cssLoaderOptions: {
                    localIdentName: '[path]___[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                },
            },
        ],
        [withBundleAnalyzer],
    ],
    nextConfig,
);
```

Do you know what is wrong with this?

**Edit**

It seems there is a compatibility problem with ant design and I found [some sources](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8054) but not get it though!

Comment: It's not helping. The problem is ant design and nextjs compatibility!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on this example in the Next.js repository 
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design

To resolve this problem, add these lines to your `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/;
      const origExternals = [...config.externals];
      config.externals = [ // eslint-disable-line
        (context, request, callback) => { // eslint-disable-line
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ];

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

An example of what the `next.config.js` file would look like:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.css'] = file => {};
}

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/;
      const origExternals = [...config.externals];
      config.externals = [ // eslint-disable-line
        (context, request, callback) => { // eslint-disable-line
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ];

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withCss],
    [
      withSass,
      {
        cssModules: true,
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          localIdentName: '[path]___[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```